# Add a view under the set header in a section

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to add a view under the header of a section in a `UITableView`. Is that possible? Here's my code so far, with that code it replaces the section:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 4) {
        return 10;
    } else
    {
        return 20;
    }
}


-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 4) {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 10)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        return view;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: @EvgeniyS You are misunderstanding me: I want to display the normal header and then the view (just a black line) and then the rows and then again the normal headers of the sections

Comment: @0x7fffffff How can I do that, if want to display the view right under the header of section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, I wouldn't think of this as adding another view underneath your header. Instead, consider making your header the height that you want the header to be + the height of the black line. Then, all you have to do is create an additional view (the black line) and add it as a sub view of the header, ex

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 10)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, view.frame.size.height - 2.0, view.frame.size.width, 2.0)];
[lineView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[view addSubview:lineView];
```